# How to prevent submitted empty fields from displaying on email form?

Tags: php, html, forms, email, syntax

I have a HTML form that when submitted, it goes through PHP Email handler.  Everything works well except that when the email is deliver, it shows all the fields including the empty ones.  I would like it to show just fields that are filled in.

I have setup an IF statement that checks to see the variable !null to display in the email, if it is null, not to display. It works to a degree. It prevents displaying the first field it encounters that is null from showing in the email, but it then prevents further fields that are valid from showing.  I believe it is a syntax error on my part.

```
<?php
$company_name = $_REQUEST['company_name'];
$contact = $_REQUEST['contact'];
$delivery_date = $_REQUEST['delivery_date'];
$delivery_time = $_REQUEST['delivery_time'];
$delivery_address = $_REQUEST['delivery_address'];
$phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];
$special_instruction = $_REQUEST['special_instruction'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$payment = $_REQUEST['payment'];

$mail->Body    = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<body>
  <p>
    <strong>Company Name:</strong> <span style="color:red;">'.$company_name.'</span><br />';
    if(!is_null($contact)){echo'<strong>Contact:</strong> <span style="color:red;">'.$contact.'</span><br />';};
    '<strong>Delivery Date:</strong> <span style="color:red;">'.$delivery_date.'</span><br />
    <strong>Delivery Time:</strong> <span style="color:red;">'.$delivery_time.'</span><br />
    <strong>Delivery Address:</strong> <span style="color:red;">'.$delivery_address.'</span><br />
    <strong>Phone:</strong> <span style="color:red;">'.$phone.'</span><br />
    <strong>Special Instruction:</strong> <span style="color:red;">'.$special_instruction.'</span><br />
    <strong>Email:</strong> <span style="color:red;">'.$email.'</span><br />
    <strong>Type of Payment:</strong> <span style="color:red;">'.$payment.'</span><br />
  </p>
</body>
</html>';
?>
```

The "Contact" field is sometime filled in, but not always.  I am trying to setup the PHP to display the information only if the field has data submitted to it.  The results should look like something like this if the Contact field has no data:

*** General Information ***

Company Name: Bl

Delivery Date: 01/03/2019

Delivery Time: 12:00

Delivery Address: Tester

Phone: 763601789

Email: Test@yahoo.com

Type of Payment: Mastercard

The results should look like this if the Contact field is filled in:

*** General Information ***

Company Name: Bl

Contact: Guy Tester

Delivery Date: 01/03/2019

Delivery Time: 12:00

Delivery Address: Tester

Phone: 763601789

Special Instruction: Help

Email: Test@yahoo.com

Type of Payment: Mastercard

Currently the results look like this:

*** General Information ***

Company Name: Test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not building the string after your conditional statement. Instead of using `echo` you need to append to the string using `.=` operator. In other words, make sure you're assigning and appending your string to the `$mail->Body` variable. You probably want to use `!empty($contact)` rather than `!null($contact)` also : )

```
<?php
$mail->Body = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<body>
  <p>
    <strong>Company Name:</strong> <span style="color:red;">'.$company_name.'</span><br />';
    if (!empty($contact))
    {
        $mail->Body .= '<strong>Contact:</strong> <span style="color:red;">'.$contact.'</span><br />';
    }
    $mail->Body .= '<strong>Delivery Date:</strong> <span style="color:red;">'.$delivery_date.'</span><br />
    <strong>Delivery Time:</strong> <span style="color:red;">'.$delivery_time.'</span><br />
    <strong>Delivery Address:</strong> <span style="color:red;">'.$delivery_address.'</span><br />
    <strong>Phone:</strong> <span style="color:red;">'.$phone.'</span><br />
    <strong>Special Instruction:</strong> <span style="color:red;">'.$special_instruction.'</span><br />
    <strong>Email:</strong> <span style="color:red;">'.$email.'</span><br />
    <strong>Type of Payment:</strong> <span style="color:red;">'.$payment.'</span><br />
  </p>
</body>
</html>';
?>
```

Comment: Partly; they want to check for empty fields, per *"**How to prevent submitted empty fields** from displaying on email form?"*. Personally, I'd use a `foreach` against `empty()` or ternary operators.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I'd definitely use ternary operators : )

Comment: Been Googling a bit (lol!). [Here's one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12524572/1415724) that I had in mind. I've used a  similar method like that before and works quite well. And [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26006189/1415724). But a ternary would probably  be kind of easier. Edit: But a `foreach` works great when there are a lot of inputs.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Yea that's one solution for sure, it's very dependant on the use case isn't it. I normally use some sort of loop at the top to validate everything and to format it, then ternary statements when building the email string like this: `!empty($value) ? $email->body .= 'Label: ' . $value : $email->body .= '';`. This has the advantage of being able to conditionally include the fields label in the email. But both are equally valid : )

Comment: Right you are. The `foreach` with the key values I like to use for sending something that's also HTML formatted in an HTML table that will automatically populate itself according to what was submitted, but that's probably beyond the scope of the question :-) but it does serve me quite well. *Cheers*

Comment: I'm always interested to hear how others do things, although I know that that's not always what comments are meant for : ) always happy to chat haha

Comment: Hey Matt!  Thanks this work perfectly...  I just want to ask one more question to make sure everything works out...

Could I use the same syntax with another section in my code...  Here is an example

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>
  <strong>LONDON BROIL:</strong> '.$london_broil.'<br />
  <strong>Special instruction:</strong> '.$special_london_broil.'
</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>
  <strong>HAM:</strong> '.$ham.'<br />
  <strong>Special instruction:</strong> '.$special_ham.'
</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

Comment: Sure thing @Delmore